# Cannot create hyperlink in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore, sitecore8, rich-text-editor, sitecore8.1

As stated in the subject I am having an issue with Sitecore 8.1
The thing is that when I go to an item in the CMS and try to create a hyperlink in the rich-text-editor I got this select item hanging. It is showing like 'loading' but it goes infinitely - never stops. 
Could someone help me?

Comment: As a first step I would suggest looking at the Sitecore logs for the moment you clicked the button. Also, you might try checking the browser console.

Comment: As @MartinDavies said check you logs and also first time load it takes some time so please wait for some time.

Answer (score 1):

If this was an upgraded environment from an earlier version of Sitecore (7.x) to Sitecore 8.1, I would verify that the appropriate /sitecore/shell files are on the file system for the 8.1.

A way to do this is to take the 8.1 zip file download, and just copy over the sitecore/shell folder.  This should ensure that all appropriate 8.1/speak files exist as intended.

If this was a fresh install of sitecore 8.1, then as suggested in comments, I would look through logs to see if you can identify a suspect log error.

Comment: The problem was in one of the libraries implementing Owin. I managed to resolve the by updating various OWIN related libraries used in the solution.